# How to join two tables NULL filling attributes that aren't related to other table

Tags: sql, postgresql, inner-join, union

Hey im trying to join two tables

```
Table1
M  N  a3
--------
3  a  W
3  b  Q
3  c  W
3  d  Q

Table2
M  N  a4
--------
3  e  M
3  f  K
3  g  K
3  h  M
```

I want:

```
Result:
M  N  a3 a4
-----------
3  a  W  ∅ 
3  b  Q  ∅
3  c  W  ∅
3  d  Q  ∅
3  e  ∅  M
3  f  ∅  K
3  g  ∅  K 
3  h  ∅  M
```

I tried:

```
select M, N, a3, a4
from Table1 t1
join Table2 t2 on (t1.M = t2.M and t1.N = t2.N)
```

I tried this but it gives me a null set since the N from T1 is disjoint from the N in T2.
Is there a way to null fill the columns that aren't related to that table specifically like what is described in the example code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want `union all`:

```
select m, n, a3, null as a4 from table1
union all select m, n, null, a4 from table2
```

If there are `(m, n)` tuples that are common between the two tables, and you want them on a single row in the resultset, then it is a bit different. You can `full join`:

```
select coalesce(t1.m, t2.m) as m, coalesce(t1.n, t2.n) as n, t1.a3, t2.a4
from table1 t1
full join table2 t2 on t2.m = t1.m and t2.n = t1.n
```

Comment: THANKS! The first one was what I was looking for!